# How can i change select box arrow when its have background color

Tags: css

i have a select box to style with css like this.

[image: Target select box]

My style

```
select {
  background-color: #b9def8;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 60px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #676863;
  background: url('../img/arrow-dropdown.png') no-repeat right #ddd;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

But with style above, normal select box become a select box like this.

[image: Style Select box]

What can i do now? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your PNG is just the gray part, and not the blue part?

Comment: My PNG images is a arrow with blue part around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned that the your png is an arrow with blue color around it. So if you are looking to get the select box with blue background, change the color in your background tag.

```
background: url('../img/arrow-dropdown.png') no-repeat right #ddd;
```

to

```
background: url('../img/arrow-dropdown.png') no-repeat right #b9def8;
```

Remember the last rule in your style is the one that's chosen and since you have applied #ddd to your background tag, you are not getting the blue background. Try and let me know if this works.